# Basic problems to use Vaadin 7 + Grails 2.3 (Persistence, domain class design, get Hibernate Session)

Tags: grails, vaadin

I'm using Vaadin 7 + Grails 2.3, there is some questions

My domain classes

```
class Base {

private static final Date NULL_DATE = new Date(0)
Date createdAt  = NULL_DATE;
Date updatedAt  = NULL_DATE;

def beforeInsert(){
    createdAt = new Date();
    updatedAt = new Date();
}

def beforeUpdate(){
    updatedAt = new Date();
}

static mapping = {
    autoTimestamp true
 }
}


abstract class Person extends Base{ 

String name;
String name2;
String phone1;
String phone2;

static constraints = {
    name2 nullable:true
    phone1 nullable:true
    phone2 nullable:true            
}


}


class Customer extends Person {

double credit;

}
```

**THE PROBLEMS**

---

**PROBLEM 1**

In my Vaadin class UI, if I try this

```
 class MyUI extends UI {

@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {

    Customer customer = new Customer()
    customer.name="RODRIGO"
    customer.save()
 }
}
```

Show this error

Servlet.service() for servlet [VaadinServlet 0] in context with path [/AgileWeb] threw exception [com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: name for class: agileweb.Customer
Possible solutions: all] with root cause
**Message: No such property: name for class: agileweb.Customer**
Possible solutions: all

there is no "name" property? The class Customer extends Person that has this property.

---

**PROBLEM 2**

If I try this

```
       Customer customer = new Customer()
   Customer.setName("RODRIGO")
   Customer.save()
```

Show thos error : **Message: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here**

I have seach about this error but I didn't understand to fix it, maybe I'm new with Grails

---

**PROBLEM 3 - ACTUALLY IS A QUESTION**

I know that I can use BeanItemContainer, just from List object, that is possible with no problem, but BeanItemContainer is not lazy load, I'd like to use HbnContainer addon (https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/hbncontainer) becase it just need a hibernate session, so How Can I get the "Hibernante session", is there any example and how to do it?

---

**PROBLEM 4 - ACTUALLY IS A QUESTION (AGAIN)**

Following this tutorial https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Vaadin%20on%20Grails%20-%20Database%20access

It works to save object in the database, but the questions
- Is it really necessary to create a service for each domain class? I have read that it's recomend to put domain logical in the services, I agree with this, but what about simple domain that no need any logical?

- so, is there possible to create something like DAO for services? is there any service design to avoid repeted code just to save objects?

---

I know that are many questions but I think these questions are the same of others, I really want to use Vaadin + Grails to enjoy the better of both, but is not easy to me at the moment!

Comment: I am planning to put more tutorials on vaadin.com. These question will help with selection of the topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Before I start answering your question, let me question you domain model. Base class is generally fine, but I want to talk about Person and Customer. You may have good reasons why you picked up inheritance, but please think of composition. Maybe you could have Person that contains a reference to an enum, that states type of the person. You could start here with that: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

1. I think you have a typo there. Call save() method on 'customer' not 'Customer', which is a class
2. When there is a request coming to Grails application, it opens a session and the session is available during that request. There is not this kind of behavior like that in Vaadin. You need to put it into a Service. Yes, you can make generic service to save an object

   class GenericService { def save(def domain) { domain.save(failOnError:true) }}
3. You can get the session factory like this

   import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder as AH

   def ctx = AH.application.mainContext
   def sessionFactory = ctx.sessionFactory

   or
   ApplicationContext applicationContext = grailsApplication.mainContext
   ConfigurableLocalSessionFactoryBean factory = applicationContext.getBean('&sessionFactory')
4. As I wrote, you could create GenericService or a service per domain object. Just to keep in mind that GenericService should only save an object and contain no other logic that would be specific for a domain object.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply.

It's very interesting you said, "Composition over inheritance" I'm going check it better. 

Congratulations and thanks for vaalinonrails website